# Getting session's remaining time for expiry in liferay

Tags: session, liferay

I am using liferay 6.1, In a particular jsp, when a session expires and when some button is clicked it loads the login page within the jsp instead of redirecting. 
My code would look like this,

```
var liferaySession = Liferay.Session._currentTime;
 if(liferaySession == '0'){
 //  reload page
  }
 else{
  // navigate to othr page.
   }
```

The same was working fine in liferay 5.

THnks in advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question.

Comment: my question is , is there a alternate to replace 'Liferay.Session._currentTime' so that i can identify the session time out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using the following code.

```
         Liferay.on('sessionExpired', 
          function(event) {  
         liferaySession = 0;
         } );
```